# How to plot boxplots with multiple columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a data frame from csv by [Credit Card Fraud Detection](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud) at Kaggle. I tried to see the range of amounts for each columns named `V#`, but it is hard for me to code this.

here is dataframe:

```
             Time          V1          V2   ...         V27         V28    Amount  Class
     0        0.0   -1.359807   -0.072781   ...    0.133558   -0.021053    149.62      0
     1        0.0    1.191857    0.266151   ...   -0.008983    0.014724      2.69      0
     2        1.0   -1.358354   -1.340163   ...   -0.055353   -0.059752    378.66      0
   ...        ...         ...         ...   ...         ...         ...       ...    ...
284804   172788.0    1.919565   -0.301254   ...    0.004455   -0.026561     67.88      0
284805   172788.0   -0.240440    0.530483   ...    0.108821    0.104533     10.00      0
284806   172792.0   -0.533413   -0.189733   ...   -0.002415    0.013649    217.00      0
```

I want to plot with,

- X axis : the range of Amount
- Y axis : V1, V2, ... V28

It is not important whether using [matplot](https://matplotlib.org/) or [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/).

please help me for making plot as like following image. This is what I want to display:

[image: expected]

Comment: Maybe `sns.boxplot(data=df[df.columns[1:29]], orient='h')` works for you? Alternatively, you could convert the dataframe to "long form" (via `pd.melt()`) and use those transformed columns for the boxplot.

Comment: or use `filter` like this `sns.boxplot(data=df.filter(regex='V\d+'), orient='h')`